# Jalapeno peppers odd yellow color

Tags: peppers, jalapenos

I have some jalapeno peppers that have some strange colors. I have grown peppers for ~5 years and never seen a jalapeno starting out yellow and never turning color. It normally is green and often turns red.
Planted Apr28 from 4-pack seedlings from Home Depot (from Masterpiece Flower Company). The nearest neighbor plants are Zucchini and Habenero. Current size: ~18-20" tall. The peppers from all 4 plants are yellow!
None are changing to green.[image: Yellow Jalapeno peppers].

Comment: Looks more like [Hungarian Banana Peppers](https://www.amazon.com/Sweet-Hungarian-Yellow-Pepper-Seeds/dp/B07MDP81B1/ref=asc_df_B07MDP81B1/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=563646983247&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=8362571010911225348&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9004053&hvtargid=pla-1828382197592&psc=1&gclid=CjwKCAjw-vmkBhBMEiwAlrMeF41IsT_M6sUIdH6UkXU85QX0k_6crPVGWTNEXkUmpz_P_Ojp13qffhoC8M8QAvD_BwE). Unlike Jalpeno, they have no wrinkles.

Comment: @YosefBaskin, I think you are correct, so you should make it an answer, I will upvote it

Comment: [Jaloro peppers](https://www.chilipeppermadness.com/chili-pepper-types/medium-heat-chili-peppers/jaloro-chili-peppers/)?

Comment: Welp, it doesn't appear to be 'just' Hungarian banana peppers. I tasted one of these and they are definitely hot! I'm thinking maybe something in the garden cross pollinated?  Maybe some hybrid?

Comment: to 333RayD777: Jaloro Pepper, https://www.cayennediane.com/peppers/jaloro-pepper-yellow-jalapeno/ so it was a supplier that may of mass mixed up the supply

Comment: I had the same thing happen where I bought a 3 pack of green jalapeño peppers & they're all yellow! At first I thought proximity to my banana peppers caused them to turn yellow. But after checking they match the Jaloro pepper. They are hot. I'm saving the seeds cause never seen or heard of a yellow jalapeño before!

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: don't worry.

Hypothesis1: got cross pollinated by another type of capsicum. Result: will be half as hot(spicy).

Hypothesis2: it's normal, You just didn't notice it previous years.

Hypothesis3: slightly different species to what You are used to.

Pick when red but also if one of them starts to show signs of lack of water<forgot the word, it gets wrinkly: then pick all of them >